Error [InteractionAlreadyReplied]: The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred when autosending images
Iam trying to make a slash command for my discord bot which will automatically send 1 image from e621 for example every one minute. It works for several. But then throws an error and the bot crashes.
error:
Error [InteractionAlreadyReplied]: The reply to this interaction has already been sent or deferred.
    at ChatInputCommandInteraction.reply (/home/******/Desktop/discorde6Bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/InteractionResponses.js:102:46)
    at Timeout.spamLoop [as _onTimeout] (/home/******/Desktop/discorde6Bot/commands/e621spam.js:117:29)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'InteractionAlreadyReplied'
}

code:
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");
const axios = require('axios');
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const activeSpams = new Map(); // Map to store active spams by guild ID and channel ID
const imageCache = new Map(); // Map to store cached images by guild ID and channel ID

// MongoDB configuration
const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI; // Replace with your MongoDB connection URI
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

async function getRandomImages(tags) {
  const e621ApiUrl = `https://e621.net/posts.json?tags=order:random+${tags}&limit=100`; // Fetch 100 posts

  try {
    const response = await axios.get(e621ApiUrl, {
      headers: { "User-Agent": "Discord Bot (********** on 621)" },
      maxContentLength: 8 * 1024 * 1024, // Limiting max content length to 8MB
    });

    return response.data.posts.map(post => ({
      imageUrl: post.file.url,
      artist: post.tags.artist.length !== 0 ? post.tags.artist : "Unknown",
    }));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching random images from e621:", error);
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch random images from e621");
  }
}

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('e621spam')
    .setDescription('Start or stop sending random images from e621 with the given tags')
    .addStringOption(option =>
      option
        .setName('action')
        .setDescription('Start or stop spamming')
        .setRequired(true)
        .addChoices(
          { name: 'Start', value: 'start' },
          { name: 'Stop', value: 'stop' }
        ))
    .addStringOption(option =>
      option
        .setName('tags')
        .setDescription('Tags to search for')
        .setRequired(false))
    .addIntegerOption(option =>
      option
        .setName('interval')
        .setDescription('Interval between sending images (in minutes)')
        .setRequired(false)),

  async execute(interaction) {
    const action = interaction.options.getString('action');
    const tags = interaction.options.getString('tags')?.split(',') || [];
    let interval = interaction.options.getInteger('interval');

    // Validate interval to be between 1 and 20
    if (interval && (interval < 1 || interval > 20)) {
      await interaction.reply({ content: "Interval must be between 1 and 20 minutes.", ephemeral: true });
      return;
    }

    const guildId = interaction.guildId;
    const channelId = interaction.channelId;
    const spamKey = `${guildId}-${channelId}`;

    if (action === 'start') {
      if (activeSpams.has(spamKey)) {
        await interaction.reply({ content: "There's already an active e621spam in this channel.", ephemeral: true });
        return;
      }

      const spamLoop = async () => {
        try {
          if (!interaction.channel.nsfw) {
            await interaction.reply("This command can only be used in NSFW channels.");
            clearInterval(activeSpams.get(spamKey));
            activeSpams.delete(spamKey);
            return;
          }

          let images = imageCache.get(spamKey);

          console.log("Images in cache:", images); // Add this line to check the content of the image cache

          // If image cache is empty, fetch new images
          if (!images || images.length === 0) {
            images = await getRandomImages(tags);
            imageCache.set(spamKey, images);
          }

          // Send the last image in the list
          const { imageUrl, artist } = images.pop();

          // Create an embed message
          const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle('Random Image from e621')
            .setDescription(`[View Image](${imageUrl})`)
            .setImage(imageUrl)
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            .setFooter({ text: `Artist: ${artist}` });

          // Send the embed message
          await interaction.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });

          // If image cache is empty after sending, fetch new images
          if (images.length === 0) {
            images = await getRandomImages(tags);
            imageCache.set(spamKey, images);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error in e621spam execution:", error);
          await interaction.reply("Something went wrong. Sorry");
          clearInterval(activeSpams.get(spamKey));
          activeSpams.delete(spamKey);
        }
      };

      // Start the spam loop only if the interval is valid
      if (interval) {
        const spamInterval = setInterval(spamLoop, interval * 60 * 1000); // Convert minutes to milliseconds

        // Store active spams in MongoDB
        try {
          await mongoClient.connect();
          const database = mongoClient.db('bot_db'); // Replace with your MongoDB database name
          const collection = database.collection('activespams');

          await collection.insertOne({ spamKey, guildId, channelId, interval });
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error storing active spam in MongoDB:", error);
        } finally {
          await mongoClient.close();
        }

        activeSpams.set(spamKey, spamInterval);
        await interaction.reply({ content: "e621spam started!", ephemeral: true });
      } else {
        await interaction.reply({ content: "Interval must be provided and be between 1 and 20 minutes.", ephemeral: true });
      }

    } else if (action === 'stop') {
      if (!activeSpams.has(spamKey)) {
        await interaction.reply({ content: "There's no active e621spam in this channel.", ephemeral: true });
        return;
      }

      // Remove active spam from MongoDB
      try {
        await mongoClient.connect();
        const database = mongoClient.db('bot_db'); // Replace with your MongoDB database name
        const collection = database.collection('activespams');

        await collection.deleteOne({ spamKey });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error removing active spam from MongoDB:", error);
      } finally {
        await mongoClient.close();
      }

      clearInterval(activeSpams.get(spamKey));
      activeSpams.delete(spamKey);
      await interaction.reply({ content: "e621spam stopped!", ephemeral: true });
    }
  },
};



tried to use interaction.FollowUp or interaction.DeferReply but with same result. im expecting it to keep sending forever until i use a command for it to stop

when exactly does this error occur? on what action and does it send any images?

According to the error, the problem is the catch of your spamLoop execution. The second line is another interaction.reply(). What happens most likely is you reply for the first time with the "e621spam started!" message and, when some unknown error pops up, the bot tries to reply saying there was an error to the same interaction again, which is not possible. You mentioned you already tried .followUp(), but did you try it only in the error line?
catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in e621spam execution:", error);
    await interaction.reply("Something went wrong. Sorry"); // THIS LINE
    clearInterval(activeSpams.get(spamKey));
    activeSpams.delete(spamKey);
}

Also, if you get to solve the previous error, correct the following as well. There is another interaction.reply() when you want to inform the loop was stopped.
await interaction.reply({ content: "e621spam stopped!", ephemeral: true });

Every interaction object must only have a single interaction.reply().
Here's the API documentation with more info about follow ups.
